# Adding Dynamic Fields to Domain Object in Grails

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I am trying to find a way to add dynamic fields to a grails domain class.  I did find the dynamic domain class plugin based on Burt's article, but this is way too much for our needs.

Supposed we have a domain class of person:

```
class Person extends DynamicExtendableDomainObject {
    String firstName
    String lastName

    static constraints = {
        firstName(nullable: false, blank: false, maxSize: 50)
        lastName(nullable: false, blank: false)
    }
}
```

Now customer **a** wants to also have a birthdate field in this. By using some sort of management tool, he adds this extra field in the database.

Customer **b** wants to also have a field middle name, so he is adding the field middle name to the person.

Now we implemented a `DynamicExtendableDomainObject` class, which the Person class inherits from.  This adds a custom field to each Domain class inheriting from this to store the dynamic properties as `JSON` in it (kind of like KiokuDB in Perl stores them).

Now when Person is instantiated, we would like to add those dynamic properties to the Person class, to be able to use the standard Grails getter and setter as well as Templating functions for those.

So on customer **a** we could use the scaffolding and person would output firstName, lastName, birthDate, on customer b the scaffolding would output firstName, lastName, middleName.

The storing of the properties will be implemented by using the `saveinterceptor`, to serialize those properties to JSON and store them in the special field.

But we have not yet found a way to add these JSON properties dynamically to the domain class during runtime.  Is there a good way to handle this?  And if so, how to best implement this?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood your problem, but couldn't you just have used a map with additional values per each Person record, instead of fiddling with the domain class?

Comment: Do you have an example somewhere using the map solution (or a plugin that uses this method, so I can take a look at it)?  How does the map solution work with validation?  How does gorm/hibernate store thos maps?

Comment: See: http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#sets,ListsAndMaps Hibernate will create another table to store the map values, something like `person_MapName`. I'm not sure how to go about validation, though, you would have to implement a custom validator.

Comment: Well with the map solution, you only have a key value store (at least from what I understood from reding over the documentation) and you can not have complex objects or datastructures.  With the JSON solution you can have more complex datastructures in it.

Comment: You're right, it is a key/value store indeed, I just thought it could be easier than fiddling with the domain class. It actually can handle complex objects, provided that they are objects of another domain class, but I think that would leave you with the same problem -- only in a separated domain class.

Comment: Not sure but, some of this might be possible with Groovy AST Transformation. We have some domain objects that we transform at compile time but we're sure about what we want to add and persist in our case. You can read up on ASTTransformation for runtime usage.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to add the properties at runtime to the DomainClass of type `DynamicExtendableDomainObject` by expanding getProperty(), setProperty(), setProperties() in the metaClass and then use beforeUpdate(), beforeInsert() and afterLoad() to hook into Persistence.

For example in Bootstrap (or service):

```
def yourDynamicFieldDefinitionService

for(GrailsClass c in grailsApplication.getDomainClasses()){
    if(DynamicExtendableDomainObject.isAssignableFrom(c.clazz)){
        Set extendedFields = yourDynamicFieldDefinitionService.getFieldsFor(c.clazz)

        //getProperty()
        c.clazz.metaClass.getProperty = { String propertyName ->
            def result
            if(extendedFields.contains(propertyName)){
                result = delegate.getExtendedField(propertyName)
            } else {
                def metaProperty = c.clazz.metaClass.getMetaProperty(propertyName)
                if(metaProperty) result = metaProperty.getProperty(delegate)
            }
            result
        }

        //setProperty()
        c.clazz.metaClass.setProperty = { propertyName , propertyValue ->
                    if(extendedFields.contains(propertyName)){
                        delegate.setExtendedField(propertyName, propertyValue)
                        delegate.blobVersionNumber += 1
                    } else {
                        def metaProperty = c.clazz.metaClass.getMetaProperty(propertyName)
                        if(metaProperty) metaProperty.setProperty(delegate, propertyValue)
                    }
                }

        //setProperties()
                def origSetProperties = c.clazz.metaClass.getMetaMethod('setProperties',List)
                c.clazz.metaClass.setProperties = { def properties ->
                    for(String fieldName in extendedFields){
                        if(properties."${fieldName}"){
                            delegate."${fieldName}" = properties."${fieldName}"
                        }
                    }
                    origSetProperties.invoke(delegate,properties)
                }
    }
}
```

with

```
abstract DynamicExtendableDomainObject {
    String yourBlobField
    Long blobVersionNumber //field to signal hibernate that the instance is 'dirty'

    Object getExtendedField(String fieldName){
        ...
    }

    void setExtendedField(String fieldName, Object value){
        ...
    }

    def afterLoad(){
        //fill your transient storage to support getExtendedField + setExtendedField 
    }

    def beforeUpdate(){
        //serialize your transient storage to yourBlobField
    }

    def beforeInsert(){
        //serialize your transient storage to yourBlobField
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are using `delegate."${fieldName}"` instead of `owner."${fieldName}"`? Thanks